# Trying to find the fastest way to navigate a set of edges in a graph

Tags: c#, algorithm, graph-algorithm

I'm unsure of which algorithm I should use to accomplish this task.  I have a graph of nodes.  Some nodes are connected with a weighted line that are required to be traversed.  However, every node is connected with a weighted, bi-directional line.  Only some of the lines must be traversed while the others are just for navigation.  I need to find a path to go over all these required lines (bi-directional), but only go over the lines one time.  I know which node I must start with.

The real-world problem is that I have a list of edges that need cut from a CNC pattern.  I'm trying to decrease the amount of time the CNC machine spends cutting out this pattern.  I know I always want to start at the origin, but I don't care where the pattern ends, just as long as all the little pieces in the pattern are cut out.  I know how long each edge of the pieces will take to cut out, and the machine is accurate enough that it can lift up the head and go to any point to start from that position.  My graph isn't huge, maybe up to 100 nodes in a general case.

This is unlike the travelling-salesman because I don't have to start and end at the same place, and I'm allowed to (and required) to hit a node multiple times.

Djikstras algorithm doesn't work because I need to traverse all the nodes to get all the edges cut... I'm not just trying to find the fastest way from point A to B.

Bonus, I need this implemented in C#, but even if I just knew what algorithm, I can probably get it programmed.

Here is a sample picture of a pattern I need to cut out.  Note, there is one diagonal and one arc I forgot to assign a weight to, which can be 50 for the diagonal, and 75 for the arc:
[image: Here is a sample picture of a pattern I need to cut out]

Comment: Every shape has a start and and end? Not sure if a graph is the best approach here.. And these shapes are already laid out on the sheet or is that also part of the optimization problem?

Comment: Ah wait you have alreadty worked out the distances between every stop-start point, and those are the edge weights?

Comment: Correct... the edges are what is weighted which is really the amount of time it takes to go from node A to node B (or whatever node).  The shapes are mostly rectangles, but occasionally have an arc within the rectangle.

Comment: Do the shapes share edges? Perhaps an example would help clarify the question.

Comment: Yes, they can share an edge, so it only needs to be cut one time.  I will provide a picture of something that is cut out, I just need to get it together.

Comment: @user3386109 I added an image of a sample pattern I need to cut out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe this can be solved as a case of the route inspection problem.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Route_inspection_problem

You will need ensure that there is a eulerian circuit for the graph, which may achieved through luck or by joining the odd vertices together.

Comment: This solution looks correct to me.  In which case the question becomes how to join together vertices to complete the loops leaving either all even, or the origin and one other odd.  And that can be viewed as an example of the Stable Roommates Problem which also has a polynomial solution.  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stable_roommates_problem

Comment: I'd say that the issue essentially boils down to the Chinese Postman Problem where I have undirected edges, and I can have a vertex that just has 1 route to it.  I think, in the end, I can then just get rid of the times I trace over and just go to the next point.  Still trying to come up with a C# solution, certainly isn't trivial.

Comment: In the end... I ended up finding all the odd vertices, then drawing an artificial edge between the shortest odd vertices, then using Fleury's algorithm to trace the path.  It works like a charm and is very fast.

Answer (score 1):

I think this would still reduce to the traveling salesman problem. [TSP does not get any easier by removing the return-to-origin rule or allowing multiple visits](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/43549/what-tsp-variant-doesnt-return-to-start-point).

As such there would be no polonomial solution, and your best bet is probably an [approximate solution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Travelling_salesman_problem#Heuristic_and_approximation_algorithms).